# bundle install: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension for RedCloth, bcrypt-ruby

Tags: ruby, centos, bundler, centos6

I am getting a bundle install error only on a single CentOS 6 VM image, but no clue why the extconf.rb is not running properly through **bundler only**.

I have seen this with both RedCloth and bcrypt-ruby and the gem_make.out only contains a single line:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

I was able to install RedCloth by running `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.8'`, but then ran into the same problem with **bcrypt-ruby**.

I tried running `cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rujoisxk/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4 && ruby ext/mri/extconf.rb` and it created a Makefile successfully.  I would like to know why this is happening

```
$ bundle install --verbose

[...SNIP...]

Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4.gemspec.rz
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4.gemspec.rz
HTTP Success
Installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

        Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rujoisxk/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4 for inspection.
        Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@rujoisxk/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri/gem_make.out
        Extension: ext/mri/extconf.rb
        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:557:in `build_extensions'
        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:509:in `each'
        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:509:in `build_extensions'
        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:90:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:82:in `preserve_paths'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:89:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:106:in `install_gem_from_spec'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:97:in `with_build_args'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:105:in `install_gem_from_spec'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:89:in `run'
        (__FORWARDABLE__):3:in `each'
        (__FORWARDABLE__):3:in `__send__'
        (__FORWARDABLE__):3:in `each'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:88:in `run'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:230:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `send'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:14
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:14
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle:23
        An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
        Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '2.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:128:in `install_gem_from_spec'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:89:in `run'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:88:in `run'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:230:in `install'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `send'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:14
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/bin/bundle:14
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle:23
```

Comment: Do you have bcrypt installed (http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/epel-i386/bcrypt-1.1-2.el5.i386.rpm.html).
If you set rvm use system, an you install bcrypt-ruby for the system ruby?
Which Version of gcc are you using?

Comment: Not sure I can provide this information anymore, as I have since changed to using a new laptop and started using different VM images.  So unless I have a reason to install these gems again for something I'm working on, I'm considering my problem resolved.